# Need to make a POST call with specific type of object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a abstract class "Achievement" with subclasses "ExhibitsVisitedAchievement" and "RouteFinishedAchievement". I want to create both of these types of achievement with a POST call to respective type of API with ExhibitsVisitedAchievement object or RouteFinishedAchievement object.

I have following APIs with me.
1. GET /api/Achievements/types - to get type of achievement
2. POST /api/Achievements/ExhibitsVisited - for Exhibit visited 
3. POST /api/Achievements/RouteFinished - for route finished

I am stucked at create method because i don't understand how can i make a POST call to respective API with respective object.

Can anyone help me in this?

I am new to angular 2 so trying to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request.

Comment: can you clarify, do you use angular 2 or angular 4.3+ ? Because one uses `HttpModule` and other uses `HttpClient`,

Comment: I am using Angular 4...my html is like...
1. type field
2. title
3.description 
when user selects type, it sould pass that type only to store the data.. but while writing create method, i dont know how to pass that perticular type..
i hv gone throught document and understood how to do it but cant figure it out how can i pass that type..

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. In the question. Properly formatted. And tell us exactly where in that code you have a problem doing what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a service, and it should look like something like this :

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class AchievementService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

create(exhibitsVisitedAchievement: ExhibitsVisitedAchievement): Observable<ExhibitsVisitedAchievement> {
        const copy = this.convert(exhibitsVisitedAchievement);
        return this.http.post('/api/Achievements/ExhibitsVisited', copy).
        map((res: Response) => {
            return res.json();
        });
    }

create(routeFinishedAchievement: RouteFinishedAchievement): Observable<RouteFinishedAchievement> {
        const copy = this.convert(routeFinishedAchievement);
        return this.http.post('/api/Achievements/RouteFinished', copy)
        .map((res: Response) => {
            return res.json();
        });
    }
private convert(exhibitsVisitedAchievement: ExhibitsVisitedAchievement): ExhibitsVisitedAchievement {
    const copy: ExhibitsVisitedAchievement = Object.assign({}, exhibitsVisitedAchievement);
    return copy;
}

}
```

Comment: I already have a create service in my app 
createAchievement(achievement: Achievement): Promise<number> {
return this.achievementApiService.postUrl('/api/Achievements', JSON.stringify(achievement), {})
.toPromise()
.then(
(response: Response) => {
let newId = response.json().value as number;
let localAchievements = this.achievementCache.getValue();
achievement.id = newId;
localAchievements.push(achievement);
localAchievements.sort(AchievementService.achievementAlphaCompare);
this.achievementCache.next(localAchievements);
return newId;
})
need to write create method for type

Comment: i also have getachievement type service...

getAchievementTypes() {
        return this.achievementApiService.getUrl('/api/Achievements/types', {})
            .toPromise()
            .then(
            (response: Response) => {
                return response.json();
            }
            )
            .catch(
            (error: any) => AchievementService.handleError(error)
            );
    }

So i have these two services with me..

Sorry for the above create service code..could not type it properly..

Comment: So did you manage to do what you wanted to achieve with your service ?

Comment: i dnt know how to achieve that..when i create a method according to these services, i dont understand how can i pass type specific achievement to POST api...